# Is there a graceful way to restart a Topshelf service daily, nightly, or on a schedule?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, topshelf

The title says it all. I couldn't find anything in their docs or on the web that met my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. Doing it via the service manager in the service will leave you in a bad state, since the service won't shutdown right or it will without any process left running to say start back up. This limitation isn't really a Topshelf limitation.

You can use the recovery options and have a timer the exits the process on a given schedule; this is a bit weird but I believe people are doing it now.

Lastly, you can create a monitoring service or job that interacts with the service manager, calling restart.

Comment: Do you know of any questions on here or other resources that would be examples of those options?

Comment: Sure, it came up on the issues list a little while ago: https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/242, https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/241. Though I don't have any examples of a scheduled task that restart a service. I think you could easily doing it using `schtasks` command to execute a `net restart <servicename>` if you don't need much configuration.